# How to download file without freezing the browser using dojo?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

So, that's it.

I'm using a spring MVC controller that gets the file in bytes[] from a Service bean. The service just reads the file from disk.

No problem so far, I just need to write the bytes[] into the ResponseBody and set the response content type manually. (No problem here, or Am I missing something).

My doubt comes in my javascript code. I'm using dojo 1.7.2. 
Doing a fast research It seems I could use dojo.io.IFrame to achieve the "async" download behaviour.

Is there another way of doing this with dojo? Or is IFrame the way to go?

Also, any advice on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: indeed, using an iframe is your best option, from what you say, you won't be loading only text so you can´t really use ajax because javascript ajax is designed for text manipulations

Comment: xmlhttprequest does not yet support a response with binary data, so yea iframe +1. I do believe there are limited support with requests that contains 'blob', so - there is a `sendAsBinary` but no `getAsBinary` basically

Comment: dojo.io.IFrame +1, but it is difficult handle moment when file was downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
function downloadExcel(urlParm){        
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', urlParm);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();   
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            // $.unblockUI();
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
                if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
                    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'excelFile1.xls');
                else {
                    var link = document.createElement('a');                     
                    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.href = downloadUrl;
                    link.style = "display: none";
                    link.download = 'excelFile1.xls';
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        document.body.removeChild(link);
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);  
                    }, 100);
                }
            }
            else
                alert("HTTP return status: " + xhr.status);
        }            
    }
}
```